# can we add two vertices and an edge between them using a single gremlin query?

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am looking for a single gremlin query that can add two vertices and an edge between them. Right now I am just able to insert 2 vertices using two gremlin queries and then inserting the edge between them using one more gremlin query. I want to do all of this using a single gremlin query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add vertices and edges in a single query. A common way to do this is something like:

```java
g.addV('Person').property('name','Fred Weasley').as('a').
  addV('Person').property('name','George Weasley').as('b').
  addE('Brother').from('a').to('b')
```

Comment: Need to add pk property

Comment: Assuming you mean a Partition Key - I think that is unique to Cosmos DB and I just showed generic Gremlin.

Comment: g.addV('Person').property('name','Fred Weasley').property("pk", "pk").as('a').
  addV('Person').property('name','George Weasley').property("pk", "pk").as('b').
  addE('Brother').from('a').to('b')